# Check if a CRM user has the rights to qualify a lead via JS

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

I was trying to determine if a User can run the Qualification process without raising a CRM error.

That would be useful to hide the Qualify button when the process cannot reach its end, for example.

So, the JS should take the Guid of the user and of the Lead and determine whether the Qualification process can take place.

Any ideas?

Comment: JS can't be turned off. JS can be modified on client side. You shoudn't use JS for security issues.

Comment: What kind of errors are you expecting? Afaik the only related privileges required for qualifying a Lead include WRITE permission to Account, Contact and Oppotunity. It should be possible to verify those using the standard Ribbon Button Visbility Rules.

Comment: When a regular user tries to qualify a Lead, but he does not have the permission to do it, he gets an Access Denied error. What I want to do is to hide the Button when the user cannot run the process.

Answer (score 3):

You could add an enabled or disable rule based on a JavaScript call which checks the users security roles an example is available here: http://dynamicscrm2011.wordpress.com/2011/05/19/ribbon-customization-part-11enabledisable-ribbon-button-based-on-security-role/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but in the system the user has access to the leads in his Business Unit. So knowing the role does not help much with that.

Comment: Surely it does, but you need to check if they have the rights to write to lead, account, contact and opportunity, and create account, contact and/or opportunity